# Create Json file

Tags: ansible

How can I create a new JSON file based on the input key-value pair?
The input key/value pair can be of any number.

User input:

```yaml
filename: myfile
json:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
```

Comment: do you want to do this programatically? if so in what language? also what is the json schema you are converting to, is it flat? Heavily nested?

Comment: @bturner1273 the tag of the question should answer your questions :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a [`to_json`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data) Jinja filter in Ansible that can do just that for you.

Use it in the `content` attribute of your [`copy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html) task and you should have your desired output.

Given the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    filename: myfile
    json:
      key1: value1
      key2: value2

  tasks:
    - copy:
        content: "{{ json | to_json }}"
        dest: "{{ filename }}.json"
```

Which gives the recap

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [copy] ********************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And generate the files *myfile.json*, containing

```
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

Answer (score 2):

The task

```yaml
    - copy:
        content: "{{ {item: lookup('vars', item.var)}|to_nice_json }}"
        dest: "{{ item.filename }}.json"
      loop:
        - var: json
          filename: myfile
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat myfile.json 
{
    "json": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
    }
}
```

---

It's possible to loop more variables. For example,

```yaml
  vars:
    filename: myfile
    json1:
      key1: value1
      key2: value2
    json2:
      key3: value3
      key4: value4

  tasks:
    - copy:
        content: |
          {% for item in my_vars %}
          {{ {item: lookup('vars', item)}|to_nice_json }}
          {% endfor %}
        dest: "{{ filename }}.json"
      vars:
        my_vars:
          - json1
          - json2
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat myfile.json 
{
    "json1": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
    }
}
{
    "json2": {
        "key3": "value3",
        "key4": "value4"
    }
}
```